# Can not get any message before navigate to other page using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i need to show one alert message before navigating to another page using Angular.js and Ui-router.I am explaining my code below.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata" confirm-on-exit  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div id="SHOWDATA">
        <div id="transactionsPortlet" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="portlet-body">
                <div class="totalaligndiv">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
                        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">First Name :</span>
                        <input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="user Name" ng-model="first_name" >
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
                        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Last Name :</span>
                        <input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="user Name" ng-model="last_name" >
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUserData(billdata);"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="buttonName"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

My controller page code is given below.

```
var dashboard=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
   return {
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
           /* window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                if ($scope.billdata.$dirty) {
                    return "The form is not saved, do you want to stay on the page?";
                }
            }*/
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                    if(!confirm("The form is not saved, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here my requirement is suppose user had filled 2 given field inside the form and suddenly navigates to another page without submitting.In this condition user should get the confirmation message to stay on this page or not.Here i am using `ui-router` for navigating the view.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: why dont you use ngMessages service?

Comment: @AliSaberi : How i will use this can you give one example.